# How to calculate protrusion in raster data using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have two raster data set.

Raster 1 is soil depth data (10*10 size )
Raster 2 is ground surface data.(10*10 Cell size)

In most cases, Soildepth data is beneath the ground but in some cases, soil depth data is protruded and it's above the ground surface. Using Arcgis I want in the result Raster 3, soil depth data value and value of ground surface data wherever protrusion is present?

**The protrusion part is highlighted in Red closed to the area.**

[image]

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application of the ArcGIS Desktop product?  Are you using the Spatial Analyst extension?  What have you tried?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by " soil depth data value and value of ground surface data wherever protrusion is present"?

Comment: PolyGeo I have tried Spatial analyst in Arc gis desktop. Used raster calculator but I am not getting the desired outout

Comment: @Hornbydd In result I am looking information as  same as its in soil depth raster but where ever protrusion is present only that area I want rasters to be clipped from ground surface and added to my result raster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple `Con` operation should do what you desire, such as, in Raster Calculator:

`Con("soil_depth">"ground_surface", "ground_surface", "soil_depth")` should assign ground_surface values where the soil_depth is greater than ground_surface.

However, the context of your question is a bit confusing, since the soil depth can go below the reference zero height value of the [height datum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_datum) that you are using. That may mean either these anomalies cannot be categorised as protrusions or your input rasters have validation problems. It sounds like you are patching an orange with an apple peel. I think this is what Hornbydd was trying to decipher.

Comment: @faith_dur  IF Height (soil depth) = Height (Ground surface model)
THEN,
I want to Set Height (soil depth) = Height (Ground surface model) - 0.1 m in model builder. how to do in this case?